# vb.net datagridview export to excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

hi i have a problem regarding my code in vb.net it seems this code is correct but the result is only generating the file but not the data inside the excel file i had created here is my code

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Try
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")



        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
                    DataGridView1(j, i).Value.ToString()
            Next
        Next
        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("C:\Users\CLB Engineering Mkt\Desktop\moveoutreport.xlsx")

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()

        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        MsgBox("Success")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and also my datatable in gridview was like this.....

If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()

```
    End If

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("select stock_number, item_description, quantity, unit_measure, customers_name, f_date from tbl_move_out", con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Fill(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    con.Close()
```

can you please help me regarding this ? Thank You in Advance

Comment: [Datagridview.Rowcount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount(v=vs.110).aspx) is not actually a count of rows of data...it gets/sets the number of rows/columns that are displayed. If you want counts of the rows/columns holding data, then you need to use Datagridview.Rows.Count and Datagridview.Columns.Count to make sure your loop goes through all the cells correctly. With those changes, I was able to run your code successfully. If those changes don't work for you, I suggest setting xlApp.visible = true and stepping through your code

Comment: make sure the code is called after the data binding is done such as in the `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event. I am not sure if Interop supports the Excel `._Default` properties, so it might need `xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value = _`